# Split to list() based on condition, omiting the False elements

Tags: r, list, vector, split

What is the most elegant way to split a vector into n-Elements based on a condition?

Every separate true-block should go into its own list element. All the false elements get thrown away.

**example1:**

```
vec  <- c(1:3,NA,NA,NA,4:6,NA,NA,NA,7:9,NA)
cond <- !is.na(vec)

result = list(1:3,4:6,7:9)
```

**example2:**

```
vec_2  <- c(3:1,11:13,6:4,14:16,9:7,20)
cond_2 <- vec_2 < 10

results_2 = list(3:1,6:4,9:7)
```

It would be great to have a **general solution** for a vector `vec` and a relating condition `cond`.

**My best try:**

```
res   <- split(vec,data.table::rleidv(cond))
odd  <- as.logical(seq_along(res)%%2)
res[if(cond[1])odd else !odd]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this should work generally:

```
> split(vec[cond], data.table::rleid(cond)[cond])
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`3`
[1] 4 5 6

$`5`
[1] 7 8 9
```

Let's make it a function:

```
> f <- function(vec, cond) split(vec[cond], data.table::rleid(cond)[cond])

> f(vec_2, cond_2)
$`1`
[1] 3 2 1

$`3`
[1] 6 5 4

$`5`
[1] 9 8 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` option with `rle`

```
grp <- with(rle(cond), rep(seq_along(values) * NA^ !values, lengths))
split(vec[cond], grp[cond])
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`3`
#[1] 4 5 6

#$`5`
#[1] 7 8 9
```

Similarly with 'vec_2'

```
grp <- with(rle(cond_2), rep(seq_along(values) * NA^ !values, lengths))
split(vec_2[cond_2], grp[cond_2])
#$`1`
#[1] 3 2 1

#$`3`
#[1] 6 5 4

#$`5`
#[1] 9 8 7
```

---

Or create a grouping variable with `cumsum` and `diff`

```
grp <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(cond) < 0)) * NA^ is.na(vec)
```

Comment: 1up for using `NA^ 0`